# Export list of service connections from Oracle Service Bus in order to create a service model in EA

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, enterprise-architect

We have a complex landscape of web services on Oracle Service Bus (latest release). We use JDeveloper to maintain it and we are going to use Enterprise Architect (SparxSystems) to model it. Currently, we only have MS Visio drawings. To make sure our model matches with reality, we would like to have a list of services and service connections exported from the OSB. It would be sufficient to have a list of connections (i.e. which services call which other services) in any format, but it would be great to be able to import this information into Enterprise Architect. Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't heard of such a thing. You should also cross-post on Sparx' forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using JDeveloper, I would suggest to query the Service Bus runtime with [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/java-api/index.html?com/bea/wli/sb/management/configuration/ALSBConfigurationMBean.html). The API documentation gives samples how to connect and retrieve service configuration, see the *Querying resources* paragraph when following the link above.

You can list all proxy services and the business services they call, i.e. get their dependencies. In addition you can obtain other service information, which can be handy in the EA model.